# Is Intersection of Derivable Sets a Sufficient Condition for Composite Function Differentiability?

Tags: calculus

I'm delving into the differentiability of composite functions and seeking clarity on a specific conceptual approach. Suppose we have a function (g) that is known to be differentiable on a set (X), and another function (f) that is differentiable on a set (U). Let's consider (Y) as the range of (g) when applied to (X).

My question revolves around the intersection of (Y) and (U): If we look at the region (Y ∩U), can we assert that the composite function (f(g(x))) is differentiable in this intersection? In other words, does the intersection of the derivable ranges of (g) and (f) provide a reliable indication of the composite function's differentiability?

Any insights or explanations on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: The domain of $f\circ g$ is a subset of the *domain* of $g$, not the range of $g$, so it will be associated with $X$, not $Y$. It can easily be entirely distinct from $Y \cap U$. By the chain rule, $f \circ g$ will be differentiable everywhere in $X \cap g^{-1}(U)$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair， thank you very much I have known from your advice